# The new marker has updated its location but old marker not remove in ionic native google map

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers, marker, ionic-native

The marker is updating to new position and set a new marker but problem with old position marker not remove. `marker.remove()` not work under this `if` condition. How I remove old marker? any solution please. here is my code =>

loadMap() {

```
this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
  controls: {
    myLocationButton : true,
    myLocation : true
  },
  camera: {
    target: {
      lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude
    },
    zoom: 18,
    tilt: 30
  },
});

this.map.addMarker({
  position: { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude },
  draggable: true,
  disableAutoPan: true,
  icon: 'blue',
  title: 'Avirup'
}).then((marker: Marker) => {
  marker.showInfoWindow();

const subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(position => {
  let geoposition = (position as Geoposition);
  let latitude = geoposition.coords.latitude;
  let longitude = geoposition.coords.longitude;
  let marker : Marker
    marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
    position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    draggable: true,
    disableAutoPan: true,
    icon: { url: './assets/image/addresspin.png' ,
    size: {
        width: 30 ,
        height: 30
    }},
    title: 'Move'
  })
  marker.showInfoWindow();
   if(marker.getPosition().lat == latitude && marker.getPosition().lng == longitude){
    marker.remove()
  }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have two different markers in your code:

1. result of `this.map.addMarker()`;
2. result of `this.map.addMarkerSync()`.

You have a nested structure and you lose one marker. Probably this one which you want to remove. Try to rename at least one of the variables to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solve this problem using `addMarker()` event.  This `addMarkerSync()` event not working properly with `remove()` function.